# if there are more than x elements, divide it and append what exceed in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var unique_price = $(".price_value").get()
    var number_price = unique_price.length;
    if (number_price >=7 ){
        $(".price_list").each(function(index) {
        $(".price_value_left").append($(".price_value:eq(0)"),$(".price_value:eq(1)"),$(".price_value:eq(2)"),$(".price_value:eq(3)"),$(".price_value:eq(4)"));
        $(".price_value_right").append($(".price_value:eq(5)"),$(".price_value:eq(6)"),$(".price_value:eq(7)"),$(".price_value:eq(8)"),$(".price_value:eq(9)")); 
        });                     
    } else if (number_price >9){
        $(".price_list").each(function(index) {
        $(".price_value_left").append($(".price_value:eq(0)"),$(".price_value:eq(1)"),$(".price_value:eq(2)"),$(".price_value:eq(3)"),$(".price_value:eq(4)"),$(".price_value:eq(5)"),$(".price_value:eq(6)"));
        $(".price_value_right").append($(".price_value:eq(7)"),$(".price_value:eq(8)"),$(".price_value:eq(9)"),$(".price_value:eq(10)"),$(".price_value:eq(11)"),$(".price_value:eq(12)")); 
        });     
    }
    else {

            $(".price_value_left").append($(".price_value:eq(0)"),$(".price_value:eq(1)"),$(".price_value:eq(2)"),$(".price_value:eq(3)"),$(".price_value:eq(4)"),$(".price_value:eq(5)"),$(".price_value:eq(6)"));
    }
```

});

I have some menu where there are some items ('li') in it.
I made this code. If there are equal or more than 7 elements in the div, I get the others and put in another. Floats with an enlarge function in the should resolve but i could not do this  because there are vertical order that I need maintain.

I created the 'more than 9 elements' so they stay more equilibrated - a style thing.

But I think this code is very ugly and not dynamically acceptable.

Is there a better way to resolve this and maintain the equilibrium design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($){
    var unique_price = $('.price_value');
    if( unique_price.length > 6 ) {
        var half = ceil(unique_price.length / 2); // In case we have an odd number, we want more elements in the left "column", so we round to next higher number.
        $('.price_list .price_value_left').append($('.price_value:lt(' + (half + 1) + ')');
        $('.price_list .price_value_right').append($('.price_value:gt(' + half + ')');
    }
    else {
        $('.price_list .price_value_left').append(unique_price);
    }
});
```

What you basically want is the *greater than* (`:gt()`) and *lower than* (`:lt()`) selectors. Unfortunately, there is no `:lte` selector, that's why I put that `(half + 1)` there. I guess there is no need to explain what they do.

Comment: it was a great answer, but not worked with me with `ceil`, but with `Math.ceil` instead. Don't know if it was something I did, or not! Thanks!

Comment: @JGSilva Sorry about that, I actually did not test it. You're right, it should've been `Math.ceil`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the balance but you can use split selected elements using [`.slice()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('#left').append($elements.slice(0,7));
$('#right').append($elements.slice(7));
```

Comment: it's great so learn something new, but the Derija93 resolved de balance too! Give it a look! Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can use the best of both answers ;) I did not really understand what you meant by "equilibrium design".